# An inequality problem, wanting synthetic solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

For positive real number $a,b,c$ which satisfies $a+b+c=5$, find the minimum of $\frac{4a^2+c^2+4ab+bc}{10b+2ac}+\frac{2b}{a+c}$.

Using lagrange multipliers, the minimum is 7/4, achieved in $a=b=1, c=3$. But cannot find a synthetic solution(solution only with stuffs like AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwartz)

Some of my approach include making $\frac{2b}{a+c}=\frac{2a+2b+2c}{a+c}-2=\frac{10}{a+c}-2$, or $10b+2ac=2(a+b+c)b+2ac=2(a+b)(b+c)$, but can't go any further..

Answer (score 1):

Thus, by C-S and AM-GM twice we obtain: $$\frac{4a^2+c^2+4ab+bc}{10b+2ac}+\frac{2b}{a+c}=\frac{4a(a+b)+c(b+c)}{2(a+b+c)+2bc}+\frac{2b}{a+c}=$$
$$=\frac{4a(a+b)+c(b+c)}{2(a+b)(b+c)}+\frac{2b}{a+c}=\frac{2a}{b+c}+\frac{2b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{2(a+b)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2(a+b)^2}{a(b+c)+b(a+c)}+\frac{c}{2(a+b)}=\frac{2(a+b)^2}{2ab+c(a+b)}+\frac{c}{2(a+b)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2(a+b)^2}{\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}+c(a+b)}+\frac{c}{2(a+b)}=\frac{4(a+b)}{a+b+2c}+\frac{c}{2(a+b)}=$$
$$=\frac{4}{1+\frac{2c}{a+b}}+\frac{c}{2(a+b)}=\frac{4}{1+\frac{2c}{a+b}}+\frac{\frac{2c}{a+b}+1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\geq2-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{7}{4}.$$